# WSO2 AM Default Server IP Address

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've setup WSO2 API Manager on Ubuntu and everything seems to be working, except, when I go into the API Store and under API Console.  When I want to "Try It Out", it doesn't work.

But more specifically, when it fails, it shows the curl command, and it is showing the incorrect IP address for my server.  It is showing the default address of: 172.17.0.1

My Question is how to change this.

I have gone into /repository/conf directory and updated the carbon.xml file to change the HostName and MgtHostName settings to reflect my server's IP address.

Is there another place to set something so that 172.17.0.1 is no longer used or referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<GatewayEndpoint>` URLs with the correct hostname, in `api-manager.xml`

```
    <APIGateway>
        <!-- The environments to which an API will be published -->
        <Environments>
            <!-- Environments can be of different types. Allowed values are 'hybrid', 'production' and 'sandbox'.
                 An API deployed on a 'production' type gateway will only support production keys
                 An API deployed on a 'sandbox' type gateway will only support sandbox keys
                 An API deployed on a 'hybrid' type gateway will support both production and sandbox keys. -->
            <!-- api-console element specifies whether the environment should be listed in API Console or not -->
            <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
                <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
                <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
                <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
                <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
                        <!-- Admin username for the API gateway. -->
                <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
                <!-- Admin password for the API gateway.-->
                <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
                <!-- Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.-->
                <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
                <!-- Endpoint of the Websocket APIs hosted in this API Gateway -->
                <GatewayWSEndpoint>ws://${carbon.local.ip}:9099</GatewayWSEndpoint>
            </Environment>
        </Environments>
    </APIGateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

> showing the incorrect IP address for my server. It is showing the default address of: 172.17.0.1

it show an IP address found as local IP (so it may be a docker container or another of your IP addresses)

As already answered, the address can be changed as `GatewayEndpoint` parameter

> When I want to "Try It Out", it doesn't work

Now I will assume that the default certificate is  not trusted for the url. Though you may try to open the dev console in the browser and find out more information about `it doesn't work`

Please note the service port (8243) is different that the management port (9443) so the ssl certificate may not be trusted by the browser for the url

When having a self-signed ssl certificate, try to put the URL in the curl command to your browser and trust the certificate. Then try to call the API again